# Bash script to parse telnet output

Tags: bash, telnet

I'm attempting to create a toggle script, which reads a value obtained via telnet, then performs a command to change the same value into something else.

The if/then statement is straightforward:

```
if [ $(ID0Status) = "String1" ]
then
command1
elif [ $(ID0Status) = "String2" ]
then
command2
fi
```

Here, `ID0Status` is checked to see what string is returned. The part I'm unsure about is how to actually obtain that information. To manually obtain the information, I do the following:

```
telnet localhost port
```

Once I'm in, I type:

```
get-status
```

At which point, the output is provided with the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0"
        "status": "String1"
    },
    {
        "id": "1"
        "status": "String2"
    }
]
```

So I need a way to find the value of `status`, where `id` = `0`, return the string, and define it as the ID0Status variable.

Where do I proceed from here?

Comment: The input looks to be in a `json` format. `python` might be more appropriate

Comment: if your system has `jq` available (or can be installed), it will be very easy to call it and get the result you need. If you can use that, then edit your Q and add a `[jq]` tag. Good luck.

Comment: Also, the code you have may run `ID0Status` multiple times -- first to compare its output to "String1", then again to compare to "String2". It's generally better to run it once, store its output in a variable (e.g. statusresult=$(ID0Status)`), and then compare that variable's value multiple times. Or you could use a `case` statement instead of a bunch of `if` `elseif` etc clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Admitting, you don't want to use third party tools:

First, you should get the telnet result once for all in a variable, let's say

```
telnetStatusResult=$(ID0Status)
```

Then, to have one line for each (id, status) couple, you can use tr and sed like this:

```
telnetStatusResult=$(ID0Status |tr -d '\n' |sed -e 's/,/\n/g')
```

Edit => explanations of this script line:

- the **tr** instruction allows to join all the lines in a single one
- the **sed** instruction allows to split the single line, to several lines, each type there is a coma ','
- this way, you get each (ID, Status) couple information on one independent line

Eventually, you can then extract status for each id, and execute the corresponding command, for instance

```
telnetStatusInfoSet=$( echo "$telnetStatusResult" |sed -e 's/^.*id[ ":]*\([^"]*\)".*status[ ":]*\([^"]*\)".*$/\1;\2/' )
```

Edit => explanations of this script line:

- for each line, the **sed** instruction just extracts the value of id, and the value of status, and formats it to get a semi-colon separated information

Such a way, you will have something like:

```
0;String1
1;String2
```

Then you may loop on these couples, and execute corresponding action.

Let me know if it is enough to solve your issue.

Comment: I might need a little more explanation as to what's going on in your second and third lines of code. There are a lot of seemingly random characters, which I have no idea as to what their purpose may be.

Comment: I've just edited my initial answer, to give you maximum explanations. Is it more clear?